# Bridge Metadata panel is available in web browser?

Tags: html, browser, adobe, metadata, bridge

If I am not provided alt text for the image in the HTML Is it available adobe bridge's Metadata panel in web browser and screenreader?

Comment: Try to give some detail explanation of environment, framework and issue.

Comment: I have a web application, it has three types of serves, each service section has a separate logo. while developing application we missed alt text for the logo image.
Now I need to insert alt text each logo. If I am adding using through Adobe bridge Metadata panel to an image can web browser display the information